# is there any method "request.form" in javascript like asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, apex-code

I want request.form for apex code so iam trying in javascript for asp page there is direct method request.form but its not working in javascript... please help

Comment: Isn't it document.forms[0] to get the first form on the page etc...

Comment: can i ask you what do you wanna do?"request" have no meaning in client side!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access elements values inside form, you can use `document.forms[]` as:

```
var oForm = document.forms[1];
```

or

```
var oForm = document.forms["myFormId"];
```

Once you have form in a variable you can access your element inside form like this:

```
var myElement = oForm.elements[2];
```

or

```
var myElement = oForm.elements["elementId"];
```

Furthermore you can access the value of the element like this:

```
var value = oForm.elements["elementId"].value;
```